# In "Game Of Thrones", out of the three types of fire. Which is the hottest?

Tags: game-of-thrones

The fire we see in *Game Of Thrones* are:
- Blue Fire (Wight Viserion)
- Red/Orange Fire or Dragonfire (Rhaegal and Drogon)
- Green Fire (Wildfire)

Is it known which one is the hottest?

Comment: There may be some insight gleamed in the answers pertaining to a Q about if Dany can be burned by wildfire over at Sci-fi & Fantasy Stack Exchange: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/133135/could-wildfire-burn-daenerys-targaryen

Comment: Don't know why this was downvoted so much. Is the answer obvious? Is the question useless?

Comment: In the books, Dragonfire is usually the same colour as the dragon is. E.g.  Balerion the Black dread's fire was Black as night, so is Drogon's (Albeit streaked with red since he himself is streaked with red), Sunfyre's fire was golden as he was, Tessarion the Blue Queen's fire was cobalt etc. Dragonflame is the hottest thing in the entire world, Wildfire is considered second to that. There is no "Wight Dragon" in ASOIAF but Ice Dragons are mentioned. Their nature is unknown so their flame or lack thereof cant be commented on

Comment: My question exactly Kharo :( I thought it was a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SHORT ANSWER:**  It is possible that nobody knows.

**LONG ANSWER:**

According to real world physics, it would be 1. blue fire, 2 green fire, 3. orange fire.  I don't know if that applies to magical fire in Game of Thrones.

A substance hot enough to glow in visible light from its heat will be hottest when all its light is invisible ultraviolet.  In order of higher heat to lower heat the visible colors are:

1 violet or purple.

2. blue.
3. green.
4. yellow.
5. orange.
6. red,

And coolest of all, invisible infra-red.

Your body, and every object around you, is glowing with invisible infra-red light right now.

However, that only works for glowing material that is the same substance.

Each substance will glow with a color closer to violet and eventually ultraviolet as it gets hotter.   But different substances will glow with the same color at different temperature ranges. Thus it is possible to change the color of a flame without changing its temperature by adding a different substance to the fire.

So it would be theoretically possible for flames from one burning substance to be red and yet hotter that purple flames from another burning substance.

But in popular culture red is often considered the hottest color.  That is because natural fire is usually red or orange, hotter fires being much rarer, and non burning substances at room temperatures can be any and every color.  So red, orange, yellow, green, blue and purple can be colors of cool objects in everyday life, while red and orange are the only common colors of burning hot flames.

In popular culture the colors from hottest to coolest are:

1. red.
2. orange.
3. yellow.
4. green.
5. blue.
6. purple.

So in weather and climate temperature charts, for example, it is common to show the hottest temperatures in red and the lowest temperatures in purple, even though that is the reverse of the scientific way to depict temperatures.

If wights, dragons, and wildfire in *A Song of Ice and Fire* and/or *Game of Thrones* are bound by real world physical laws, and if the same substance is burned in each type of fire, the blue fire will be hotter than the green fire which will be hotter than the orange fire.

If different substances are burned to make the fire of wights, dragons, and wildfire, then it is possible that there is a different correlation between heat and color.

If the fire of wights, dragons, and wildfire does not follow physical laws, but some sort of magical laws, then it is possible that the relationship between heat and color follows that in popular color on Earth, and thus orange fire is hotter than green fire that is hotter than blue fire.

Or it is possible that the relationship between the heat and the color of magical fire is different from either that of physical science or popular culture.  If it is an unknown third relationship then the only way to know the heat levels of various types of magical fire would be if a character mentions it.

Comment: Could you add some references to support your answer? BTW, even in real world physics one can add some chemicals to produce coloured flames. ;)